# How to delete a structure inside another structure in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

I have a structure called Employee. This structure contain another structures like EmployeeSalary and EmployeePerformanceData. I have to delete the structure EmployeePerformanceData from the parent structure Employee. How Can I acheive this in Coldfusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When wondering how to do stuff in a programming language, googling the problem is the best place to start. I googled "[How to delete a structure inside another structure in ColdFusion](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=How%20to%20delete%20a%20structure%20inside%20another%20structure%20in%20ColdFusion)" (ie: the title of your question), and two of the first five results (the first result is this question ;-) answer your question:

- [Deleting structure elements and structures](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09f0b-7fdc.html)
- [GETTING STARTED WITH STRUCTURES IN COLDFUSION](http://coldfusionexamples.com/2010/11/14/getting-started-with-structures-in-coldfusion/)

And a third would get you on the right track, as it lists all the possible struct functions in CFML: "[Structure functions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6210.html)"

So having looked at those, the answer seems to be:

```
structDelete(Employee, "EmployeePerformanceData");
```

(When I say "seems to be", I mean "it is")

Comment: I had tried this before posting this question. That time I got an error saying "Element EmployeePerformanceData is undefined in a CFML structure referenced as part of an expression." In my case EmployeePerformanceData is a structure which contains another structure like EmployeePerformanceData1 and EmployeePerformanceData2. Any idea how to handle this

Comment: Revise your question actually ask about what you're having problems with, with *all* the relevant information (like: here's the code I tried, and how it didn't work). You cannot expect us to guess all this stuff.

Comment: Thanks Adam..it worked , actually issue was different. I had to fix this issue urgently so I had no time to search and find so I thought of posting this question quickly. Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 0):

Well, sometimes googling these things doesn't point to the right answer.

To delete structures within other structures

```
<cfset StructDelete(myStruct.mySubStruct.mySubSubStruct,"keyName")>
```

Et voilà.